# Test for convergence - Log operation

Tags: convergence-divergence, logarithms, divergent-series, indeterminate-forms

∑ Log (n / n+ 1)

I solved the above problem in two different ways.

1st Method

= Log n - Log n+1
= Log n - Log n . Log 1
= Log n - Log n . 0
= Log n
= Log ∞
= ∞ (Diverges)

Method 2

= Log ( n / n + 1 )
= Log ( n / n . (1 + 1 /n))
= Log ( 1 / 1 + (1/n))
Substituting Limit, n=> ∞
= Log ( 1 / 1 + 1 / ∞))
= Log ( 1 / 1 + 0 )
= Log ( 1 / 1 )
= Log 1
= 0 (Converges)

Method 3

u1 = -log2
u2 = log2 - log3
u3 = log3 - log4
un = logn - log(n+1)

sn = u1 + u2 + ... un
sn = - log(n+1)

sub method 1
Substituting Limit, n=> ∞

sn = - log (∞)
sn = - ∞ (diverges)

sub method 2

sn = - log(n+1)
sn = - (log n . log 1)
sn = - (log n . 0)
sn = - (∞ . 0)
sn = indeterminate form

Where am i making the mistakes. Which one is the right way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $\log\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)=\log n - \log(n+1)\Rightarrow S_n =-\log(n+1)$

Comment: In method 3, i have mentioned this step. I am confused with the next step. Can you please tell me why one of the sub method under method 3 is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

is it $\log \frac{n}{n+1} $? if yes then the first method you did something wrong $\log \left(\frac{n}{n+1} \right) = \log (n) - \log (n+1)$ you cant simplify further $\log(n+1) \ne \log(n) \log (1) $

and in the second method you used the divergence test which just tells you if the limit is not zero then the series is diverge but if it is zero you need to look for another test

Method 3 is the only correct method you used since the series converges if and only if the sequence of the partial sums converges but in your case it diverges